# Dealing with categorical columns with unbalanced value count

Tags: feature-selection, data-cleaning, preprocessing, categorical-data

I'm doing some data processing and wondering what is the best practice for dealing with categorical columns that has a value counts plot looking like the below (these are one-hot-encoded at a later stage). Should the rarely represented variables be dropped? What is a typical limit in terms of value count % that decides if they should be dropped? Should I group the categories between for example "Tug" to "Naval" as "Other"?

I realize that how the data is processed is dependent on the underlying "meaning" of the data. Nevertheless, would love some general comments on best practices for situations like this.

[image]

Comment: The Y axis on this plot doesn't look like count or proportion, what is it? My opinion is that rare values can be kept only if there is a large number if instances, because if the count is lower than 3-5 it's likely to cause more problems than to help.

Comment: The plot shows the value count for each categorical feature. So "Bulk" is represented approximately 1.2M times, whereas e.g. "Tug" is represented approximately 0.1M times.

Comment: Oh ok, sorry I missed the 1e6. So to me this is a case where rare values can be kept or removed, there's no strong reason either way.